# Mount ext4 formatted sdcard on Lineage 18.1

Tags: lineageos, android-11, ext4

I currently have Lineage 18.1 (20211007-microG-pioneer) loaded on a phone with Magisk 23. I have tried inserting an sdcard that has an `/dev/sda1` partition formatted with ext4. In the past I've used the Magisk addon "Vold - exFAT/NTFS/EXT4/F2FS Support", however I now get an "Only support Oreo 8.1" when trying to install it.

Is there any way to get ext4 sdcard support on Lineage 18.1 (fully rooted).

Comment: Doesn't LineageOS automount all partitions by default? https://review.lineageos.org/c/LineageOS/android_system_vold/+/258169

Comment: It seems like it should, but it doesn't. When I insert an ext4 formatted sdcard, I get a popup saying the sdcard isn't in a usable format and it wants to reformat it (presumably as exfat)

Comment: oh, it might have stopped working in Lineage 18.1: https://gitlab.com/LineageOS/issues/android/-/issues/3684

Comment: yes, must be some bug or lazy dev. made some test on LineageOS 17.1 it works out of the box, no Magisk module needed